# Highcharts x axis custom scaling

Tags: highcharts, axis

I'm looking to use highcharts to create a graph with a custom (1/K) scaled x-axis for a chemistry application. I need the tick marks to be spaced differently, but not in a logarithmic fashion. For example, let's say I want the spacing between the 40 Kelvin x-axis tick mark and the 50 Kelvin tick mark to be 100px (arbitrary value), but then I want the spacing between the 140 x-axis tick mark and the 150 tick mark to be smaller than that (to be consistent with the scaling). The question is, how do I make the spacing between two tick marks (both 10 Kelvin apart) different sizes (to be computed with a formula)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want using the xAxis tickPositioner function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).